# When glReadPixels can be used?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, glreadpixels

I want to know the use of `GLReadPixels` function./
How it is reading the pixels?
Is it reading `GLKView` pixels or `UIView` pixels or anything on the mainscreen which is in bounds provided in the glreadFunction.
Or it can only be used if we are using `GLKView`??

Please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

It reads pixels from the current OpenGL (ES) framebuffer. It can't be used to read pixels from `UIView`, but it can be used for reading from a `GLKView` because its backed by a framebuffer (however, you can only read its data when its the active framebuffer, which it most likely is at the time of drawing). However, if everything you want is a screenshot of your `GLKView`, you can use its built-in `snapshot` method to get an `UIImage` with its content.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.
And one more thing, how can glreadpixel used to take snapshot of the glkview which contains many subview( uiviews of glkviews)??

Comment: @KaranSehgal It can't. Also, there is no such thing as a UIView of GLKViews.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the info.really appreciate it.
I dont know opengl, Ijust wanted screenshot of a view with subviews. But renderInContext method is taking much time as i am taking screenshots frequently for making video.So i read somewhere that using opengl could solve my problem.So do you have any idead about this??

Comment: @KaranSehgal If you `GLKView` contains subviews, you simply can't capture them via OpenGL. In this case you have to use another method like `renderInContext:`, which btw is the fastest one available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use glreadPixels to read background screen. Here is code to do.

```
- (UIImage*) getGLScreenshot {
    NSInteger myDataLength = 320 * 480 * 4;

    // allocate array and read pixels into it.
    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, 320, 480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
    // there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
    GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    for(int y = 0; y &lt;480; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x &lt;320 * 4; x++)
        {
            buffer2[(479 - y) * 320 * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * 320 + x];
        }
    }

    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);

    // prep the ingredients
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * 320;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(320, 480, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    // then make the uiimage from that
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    return myImage;
}

- (void)saveGLScreenshotToPhotosAlbum {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self getGLScreenshot], nil, nil, nil);
}
```